# How to send message as a channel telethon

Tags: telethon

Is this even possible using telethon?
I want to use the send message as channel in public groups option using telethon.
I couldn't find anything about it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is this send_as attribute in send_message for the master branch of Telethon and it's not released yet.